# Flurry not sending data on android

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I am trying to use flurry analytics in my app, but no data is being sent from my phone or tablet on lollipop. The only data i have received is when i boot my tablet into a jellybean rom.

I am initializing flurry in my main activity and that should be enough to record what i need

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FlurryAgent.init(this, "KEY");
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
}
```

The log is as follows:

```
10-16 15:46:58.159 20002-20002/com.dev.app W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session started for context:com.dev.app.MainActivity@317f85c5
10-16 15:46:58.160 20002-20002/com.dev.app W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context:com.dev.app.MainActivity@317f85c5
10-16 15:46:59.253 20002-20055/com.dev.app D/FlurryAgent: Referrer file contents: null
10-16 15:47:37.797 20002-20055/com.dev.app W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session paused for context:com.dev.app.MainActivity@317f85c5
10-16 15:47:47.802 20002-20055/com.dev.app W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session ended
```

At no point does it actually send any data. I am using flurry 6.1.0 and gps-analytics 8.1.0. I don't know if the error is lollipop specific or if it is related to the referrer file or neither. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something to note. You should always configure Flurry before initializing. So `FlurryAgent.setLogLevel()` *before* `FlurryAgent.init()`. This doesn't solve your problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you happen to have any idea what's causing my problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same probleme , using flurry 6.2.0, not event showing up into "log event", but only into "Event Summary" without any data. have you succefuly solve this ?